# is there any way to send image to client by socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

I want to make a web app where you can send images in real-time. is there any way of doing it??
any video link or documentation link will be very helpful.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the official website](https://socket.io/?p=373) says, socket.io can handle blob objects.

> Starting in 1.0, it's possible to send any blob back and forth: image, audio, video.

For example, you can push documents from socket.io server-side like the following. Pushing from client-side to server-side is almost the same with this.

**Server-side**

```
const filePath = "./img.jpg"
const imgBinary = fs.readFileSync(filePath)
socket.emit("img",imgBinary)
```

**Client-side**

```
socket.on("img", imgBinary => {
    const blob = new Blob([imgBinary])
    const imgBlobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    // Insert imgBlobUrl into img.src or something
});
```